# I cant get my try catch to work in java

Tags: java, swing

So here is my GUI as you can see.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Frame1 {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textFieldnum1;
    private JTextField textFieldnum2;
    private JTextField textFieldAns;
    private Termostat thermo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Frame1 window = new Frame1();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Frame1() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        thermo = new Termostat();

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 696, 250);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        textFieldnum1 = new JTextField();
        textFieldnum1.setBounds(176, 11, 147, 46);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldnum1);
        textFieldnum1.setColumns(10);

        textFieldnum2 = new JTextField();
        textFieldnum2.setBounds(176, 154, 147, 46);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldnum2);
        textFieldnum2.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Convert to celcius");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                double myf = thermo.convertToCelcius(Double.parseDouble(textFieldnum1.getText()));
                textFieldAns.setText(String.valueOf(myf));
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(0, 0, 171, 68);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Convert to fahrenheit");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                double myf = thermo.convertToFahrenheit(Double.parseDouble(textFieldnum2.getText()));
                textFieldAns.setText(String.valueOf(myf));
            }
        });
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(0, 143, 171, 68);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);

        textFieldAns = new JTextField();
        textFieldAns.setBounds(354, 90, 147, 46);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldAns);
        textFieldAns.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Converted");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(285, 94, 112, 38);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
    }
}
```

---

And here comes my problem. When i made my class that i wanna run the input in to calculate celcius to fahrenheit, i dont want it to crash when i type anything else than numbers. but i cant get it to work so i need you guys help to get the try catch to work.
Im very thankful for all help i get.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Termostat {
    public double convertToCelcius(double input) {
        double far = 0;
        try {
            far = (input - 32) * 5 / 9;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong input");
            return far;
        }
        return far;
    }

    public double convertToFahrenheit(double input) {
        double cel = 1;
        try {
            cel = (input * 9 / 5) + 32;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong input");
            return cel;
        }
        return cel;

    }
}
```

Comment: You should try to catch a specific exception

Comment: The `try` blocks in your code do not contain any of the lines from which your exceptions are being thrown (those lines are indicated by your stack traces).  Naturally, a `catch` block is ineffective for exceptions that do not come from within the scope of their associated `try`.

Answer (score 5):

This is the line where you get probably an Exception:

```
     double myf = thermo.convertToFahrenheit(Double.parseDouble(textFieldnum2.getText()));
```

So guard it with a NumberFormatException ([parseDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the NumberUtil.isNumber(str) to check if the input is a number. [Here is more information](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

you must use try catch when you want to parse text field texts to Double using this method `Double.parseDouble(text)`

write them them like this and remove your try catches inside your `convertToFahrenheit` and `convertToCelcius` methods

```
    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Convert to fahrenheit");
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
            try { // start trying to parse input string  to double
                double myf = thermo.convertToFahrenheit(Double.parseDouble(textFieldnum2.getText()));
                textFieldAns.setText(String.valueOf(myf));
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) { // catch the exception that you mentioned
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong input");
                textFieldAns.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
```